# why is my code outputting the package.class@letternumbers in java?

Tags: java, performance, class, methods, output

as per usual I'd like to note I'M A BEGINNER, so sorry in advance if I don't use the correct terminology.

what i did:

I created a method that outputs a recipe in a separate class from the main. In the main class i created an object to call on the method from the other class.

From main:

```
Breakfast recipeName2 = new Breakfast();
recipeName2.frenchToast();  
System.out.println(recipeName2);
```

From other Class:

```
    public void frenchToast(){

        System.out.println("\n");
        StringBuilder sba = new StringBuilder("For French toast you will need:\n ");

        sba.append("Eggs\n ");
        sba.append("Bread\n ");
        sba.append("Cinnamon\n ");
        sba.append("Vanilla ");

        System.out.println(sba.toString());

    }

}
```

The problem:

Thought the recipe is outputted correctly, for some reason at the very end of it this is added as well: **ingredients.Breakfast@1f96302**

I'm not sure what it is or how to get rid of it. I've tried altering my code in different ways such as altering what i put in the **system.out.ln()** parameters, but it then messed up my code. I have a hunch this is happening because of the way something is being passed through something else, but i have tried to take alter the way i wrote my code to no avail.

I'd be very grateful if anyone could help me out. I'm continuing with my project since technically my code works, but i'm stumped by this and would really like to know why is it happening.

Thanks

Comment: What do you expect to happen when executing `System.out.println(recipeName2);`, and why?

Comment: just delete the line "System.out.println(recipeName2);"
It outputs the object reference "ingredients.Breakfast@1f96302"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error was because of the line `System.out.println(recipeName2);` below I have shown how you can use both void or String in `frenchToast()` and `frenchToast2()` respectively:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Breakfast recipes = new Breakfast();
    recipes.frenchToast();
    System.out.println(recipes.frenchToast2());
  }
}

class Breakfast {
  public void frenchToast(){
    StringBuilder sba = new StringBuilder("For French toast you will need:\n ");
    sba.append("Eggs\n ");
    sba.append("Bread\n ");
    sba.append("Cinnamon\n ");
    sba.append("Vanilla ");
    System.out.println(sba.toString());
  }

  public static String frenchToast2(){
    StringBuilder sba = new StringBuilder("For French toast you will need:\n ");
    sba.append("Eggs\n ");
    sba.append("Bread\n ");
    sba.append("Cinnamon\n ");
    sba.append("Vanilla ");
    return(sba.toString());
  }
}
```

**Equivalent Output:**

```
For French toast you will need:
 Eggs
 Bread
 Cinnamon
 Vanilla 
For French toast you will need:
 Eggs
 Bread
 Cinnamon
 Vanilla
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/GCRQ/0)

Answer (score 0):

Your Breakfast class does not override the `toString()` method. So when you are printing the breakfast object, it will use the `Object::toString` method, which prints 'an identifier @ the location in Java Heap'.

It would be better to review your object model, but a simple fix for you would be to make FrenchToast a class that extends Breakfast (or implements, if you make Breakfast an interface), and then put the Strings in the toString method.

Like this:

```
public interface Breakfast {}

public class FrenchToast implements Breakfast {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sba = new StringBuilder("For French toast you will need:\n ");
        sba.append("Eggs\n ");
        sba.append("Bread\n ");
        sba.append("Cinnamon\n ");
        sba.append("Vanilla ");

        return sba.toString();
    }
}
```